# (Proof Verification) Show that the collection of open disks is a basis for a topology on the plane

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Here's what I did.

Let $\Sigma$ be a collection of open sets for a topological space $(X,\Omega)$. By definition of a basis for the plane, $\Sigma^2$ consists of all possible open disks for the topology $\Omega$. Furthermore, since open sets in a topology $\Omega$ are defined to be the union of open disks, the collection of open disks $\Sigma^2$ must be a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Am I wrong? If so, how can I improve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Is $X=\mathbb{R}$, I don't understand where does $\mathbb{R}$ appear from in the end. Furdermore, the product of two open sets is not an open disk, If you are not in a mesurable space you have no concept of open disks, and if what you mean is the product of open intervals, what you get are open rectangles, not disks.

Comment: R^2 is just the plane. We haven't even covered measurable spaces yet so I'm not sure that's what my professor is looking for. I'm kind of confused by your response. If you could clarify more that would help

Comment: This makes no sense without knowing the text you’re basing this off IMO.

Comment: The first section on basis in Elementary Topology Problem Textbook by Vito, Ivanov, Netsvetaev, and Kharkamov.

Comment: @sroma1997 You're trying to show the collection of open disks forms a basis. Basically you need to show: 1) a plane can be written as the union of open disks (obviously); 2) for any $B_1, B_2$ in the collection and  $x\in B_1\cap B_2$, you can find another open disk $B_3$ s.t. $x\in B_3\subset B_1\cap B_2$. I think this theorem is included in most of the general topology texts, but I don't have your book.

Comment: @Kevin thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  It suffices to show that the set of all arbitrary unions of disks is closed under unions and finite intersections (and contains the plane and the empty set).